# How can I getSelection value on the TreeMap in reactjs react-google-charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

i want to get the value for the node which is selected by the user in graph.
I have tried with this solution but not getting the values.

```
const ChartEvents = [
  { eventName: "select",callback({ chartWrapper }) {console.log("Selected ", chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection());}];


<Chart chartType="TreeMap" data={data} graphID="TreeMap" options={options} width="100%" height="400px" chartEvents={ChartEvents} />
```

[codesandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-hooks-zcwehc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the `'ready'` event on the chartwrapper,
then assign the `'select'` event on the chart,
as follows...

```
const ChartEvents = [
  {
    eventName: "ready",
    callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
      const data = chartWrapper.getDataTable();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", function () {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        console.log("Selected ", selection);
        if (selection.length > 0) {
          console.log("Market trade volume (size) ", data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2));
          console.log("Market increase/decrease (color) ", data.getValue(selection[0].row, 3));
        }
      });
    }    
  }
];
```

Comment: hope this helps -- [https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-shadow-t0p1t7](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-shadow-t0p1t7)

Comment: Hi Thankyou for the solution , checked but it is not returning the value of node in console.

Comment: see edit above, need to use selection to pull value from the data table...

Comment: Thankyou verymuch was stuck on this one for a while .

Comment: Hi  @Whitehat i am facing the issue while getting the value from iterated graph. On first graph rendering it is returning value but while i move toward inside graph (which in my code example is EUR" ) then the new graph doesnt return the node value. Your take on this one would be very helpful. codesandbox -[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-northcutt-8j22zj)

Comment: not sure but for the tree map, the select event is fired when the user drills down, or rolls up a node. once you get to the last node, it no longer fires.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest any alternate solution for my case actually kind of stuck on the particular issue, any suggestion would be great help. [codesandbox link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-northcutt-8j22zj)

Comment: you might try one of the other [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap#events) for the tree map, there are more than just select event

Comment: Yes but the requirement of my operation is to get the selected node so that i can call api with same node value ,for which i am not getting the alternative events @WhiteHat